# Prevent Chrome Recorder devtool from refreshing the page

Tags: google-chrome, automation, google-chrome-devtools

I'm starting to use Chrome's new "Recorder" devtool. It's really nice; however, I don't like that it starts the automation by refreshing the page. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I can delete individual steps of the automation; however, the GUI does not let you delete the first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `#someTextHere` to the end of the `url` in the first navigation event, then at the end of the recording, add another navigation event with `#someDifferentTextHere`, the page will not refresh when you replay it.

[image]

Comment: Neat, thank you!